# hide unavailable combinations (attributes)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need hide combination does not available. I founded conditon in product.js `if (!selectedCombination['unavailable'])` but I don't know witch element it should be hide.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a PrestaShop 1.6 version, you can do it from Backoffice.

You can find it in: `Preferences` - `Products`.
Into the `Product page` section, the option is: 
`Display unavailable product attributes on the product page` - `NO`

And in the `Products stock` section: `Allow ordering of out-of-stock products` - `NO`

Ensure that the products have the option: `When out of stock` -> `Default` (in the `Quantities` section) to get the Default configuration (in this case, Deny orders).

With this configuration, the unavailable stock combinations will not appear in the Product page.